# Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(WithAuthentication)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, authentication, redux, store

**Hello !**
I have a problem, I start using React with Redux.
I started my application with Firebase authentication. I wanted to integrate Redux with my application, but I have an error because I use a HOC on my AppComponent. But I find myself with the error below:

Thanks you so much.. I do not find this type of error with a HOC on the internet .. I need to pass the history to my child components ...

***Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(WithAuthentication)". Either wrap the root component in a , or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(WithAuthentication)".***
[ErrorMessage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38TVy.png)

And here are my components:

**Index.JS**

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import App from './components/App';

import "./index.css";

import registerServiceWorker from "./registerServiceWorker";

  
ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);

registerServiceWorker();
```

**AppComponent**

```js
import React from 'react';

import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { routerMiddleware } from 'react-router-redux';

import Router from './Router';
import withAuthentication from '../Session/withAuthentication';

import rootReducer from '../../reducers';

class App extends React.Component {
  history;
  store;
  middlewares = [];

  constructor() {
    super();

    this.history = createHistory();
    this.middlewares = [routerMiddleware(this.history)];
    this.store = createStore(
      rootReducer,
      applyMiddleware(...this.middlewares)
    );
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={this.store}>
        <Router history={this.history} />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default withAuthentication(App);
```

**Router.js**

```js
import React from 'react';
import { ConnectedRouter } from 'react-router-redux';
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

import Navigation from '../Navigation';
import LandingPage from '../Landing';
import SignUpPage from '../SignUp';
import SignInPage from '../SignIn';
import ArticlePage from '../Article';
import PasswordForgetPage from '../PasswordForget';
import HomePage from '../Home';
import AccountPage from '../Account';

import * as routes from '../../constants/routes';


const Router = () => (
  <ConnectedRouter history="truc">
    <Switch>
        <Navigation />

        <hr/>

        <Route exact path={routes.LANDING} component={() => <LandingPage />} />
        <Route exact path={routes.SIGN_UP} component={() => <SignUpPage />} />
        <Route exact path={routes.SIGN_IN} component={() => <SignInPage />} />
        <Route exact path={routes.PASSWORD_FORGET} component={() => <PasswordForgetPage />} />
        <Route exact path={routes.HOME} component={() => <HomePage />} />
        <Route exact path={routes.ACCOUNT} component={() => <AccountPage />} />
        <Route exact path={routes.ARTICLE} component={() => <ArticlePage />} />

        <hr/>

    </Switch>
  </ConnectedRouter>
);

  
export default Router;
```

And my **withAuthentication.js** (that working before and didn't change)

```js
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import { firebase } from '../../firebase';

const withAuthentication = (Component) => {
  class WithAuthentication extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
      const { onSetAuthUser } = this.props;

      firebase.auth.onAuthStateChanged(authUser => {
        authUser
          ? onSetAuthUser(authUser)
          : onSetAuthUser(null);
      });
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <Component />
      );
    }
  }

  const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    onSetAuthUser: (authUser) => dispatch({ type: 'AUTH_USER_SET', authUser }),
  });

  return connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(WithAuthentication);
  
}

export default withAuthentication;
```

```
    "dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^4.3.1",
    "history": "^4.7.2",
    "prop-types": "^15.5.10",
    "react": "^16.1.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.1.1",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "react-router": "^4.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-router-redux": "^4.0.8",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.4",
    "recompose": "^0.27.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.0"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is to do with where you render your `Provider` compared to where your `connect` occurs.

You're connecting your component that contains your `Provider`.

You need to ensure that any connected component is a child of `Provider`.

```
const ContainerComponent = () => {
  const MyComponent = withAuthentication(App);
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <MyComponent />
    </Provider>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response! :) but I end up with a new problem that I do not understand:

In my App Component :
**React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child**

Comment: That's usually because you're rendering multiple children in a `return` of a render. You need to make sure that your `return`s of your render are a single element with children. `<div>content</div>`, not `<div>content</div><div>content</div>` - if that makes sense. You can usually resolve that by wrapping children in a `div`

Comment: I don't understand, because i'm sure that my returns of my render are only single element :

my **index.js**
`ReactDOM.render(
  <ContainerComponent />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);`

My **ContainerComponent.js**
`render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={this.store}>
        { withAuthentication(App) }
      </Provider>
    );
  }`

Comment: If i use `Fragment` of React around my `Provider`. It resolve this problem but i have the same error that before : 
**Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `ContainerComponent`**

Comment: Oh. If you're using my above syntax, you might want to try `{withAuthentication(App)()}`. I didn't notice that `withAuthentication` returns a component.

Comment: Ohh with this syntax i have a big error screen with the main message : **TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function**

Comment: Whoops. That's my fault. I've updated my answer. Try reflecting what I've done with `withAuthentication`.

Comment: Hm.. where do I put the creation of the store and history? (because at the moment I wrote this in the **containerComponent** (which is a class) so I can not use this syntax (see above in my question, I copied the code of my **AppComponent** in my **ContainerComponent**. **AppComponent** then just call my **Router.js** )

Comment: Generally you would create your store and history outside of your React components, then dispatch updates for any async data you might receive in your components.

Comment: Ok i understand. But actualy it's work 
BUT, i have this error (i think that it's the **history={history}** on my ConnectedRouter. I'm not sure.. It's the main (and last) error of my project: 

**Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of** `Router`

I invite you to review my syntax in my first question about this post

Comment: I'd try removing `<Navigation />` and those `<hr />`s from your router component. I think React-router's `switch` component only allows `Route` and `Redirect` components.

Comment: ERROR FIX !!!!

I use **'react-router-redux'** v4 but she's bad..
After npm install **react-router-redux@next**
I'm on  **"react-router-redux": "^5.0.0-alpha.9",**

AND IT'S WORK

Comment: But => Now my "<Link To" change the url but no redirect routes :/